# applying the pattern " so... that "

Tags: adverbs, conjunctions, word-order

Extracted from dictionary Oxford Advanced:
He had changed to such an extent(= so much) that I no longer recognised him.

Paraphrased:

> a. He had changed  **so much** that I no longer recognised him.
>
> b.  He had **so** changed that I no longer recognised him.

Would you please show me if I have reworded the sentence correctly? if not, could you teach me?

Thanks a million

Comment: I've noticed something in quite a few of your posts. Be careful about the word "learn": "to learn" means absorbing knowledge. Passing it on, is "to teach". So what happens here is we *teach*, you *learn*.

Comment: Yes, the object of the verb "to learn" is not the one who learns but the thing that is learned. "I want to learn mathematics".

Comment: You probably meant the pattern "so much", not "so that" in your headline.

Comment: When you ask if you reworded it correctly; does that mean you think the original is wrong?

Comment: No, just I am trying to rephrase the original one so that I could improve my writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He **had so changed** that I no longer recognised him

This sentence seemed strange to me at first. Why? Because you use the adverb **so** to modify the past participle **changed**, and split the combination "had changed". The past participle **changed** here is tightly linked to the verb **had**, they are used together to put the clause into the Past Perfect tense.

But I found these modern uses of this construction:

> [Evan Richardson, 2013](https://books.google.ru/books?id=gOKhQmGEV-kC&lpg=PA297&dq=%22had%20so%20changed%22&hl=ru&pg=PA297#v=onepage&q=%22had%20so%20changed%22&f=false): "My life had **so** drastically changed, and I myself had **so** changed, that seeing this old tribe at the Pierre was like a bad trip back in time that no longer applied to me." (Here we have **so** inserted between **had** and **changed**, just like in your example).

I looked in Google Books for **had so much changed**, and found several quotations from the 19th century:

> The Indians now *had **so much** changed* their deportment as to bring in horses or cows, that they found astray from the mines. (Here, the adverb **so much** splits the Past Perfect construction "had changed"; but here the verb is used transitively: it has the object "deportment", and maybe this makes the split look more natural)

Your first sentence looked more "natural" to me:

> He [had changed] **so much** that I longer recognised him.

Here, we are using the adverb **so much** to modify the whole "verb combination" **had changed**.

---

So, it is not an error to put something between a verb and its "helper". I found an interesting [little article in The Economist](http://www.economist.com/blogs/johnson/2013/01/syntax), here's a quotation:

> I didn't realise that quite so many people consider it an error to put anything between a verb and its helpers like auxiliary verbs. To this crowd, "We have always been friends" must be "We always have been friends." This is, of course, a rule that would subsume the so-called ban on split infinitives, the rule that declares "to boldly go" an error. Prof Liberman and the commenters have a roundup of the usage manuals that prescribe this false rule. One source says that the rule is "widespread among newspaper journalists", which comes as a surprise to this practitioner of the hackish arts. The Economist has no such rule, though we do tell journalists to avoid split infinitives because they annoy so many readers.

---

Reference:

- [Split Verbs](http://www.economist.com/blogs/johnson/2013/01/syntax) - The Economist, 2013
- [The True History of the Split Verb Rule](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4385) - Language Log, 2012

Comment: I love this answer, but I'm not sure I understand the essence of either the answer or the question. The question was "have I reworded this correctly?" Did that mean that we assumed the original wasn't ok? And was the answer yes, no, or something else?

Comment: @JimReynolds - I don't know why he decided to reword the sentence, but my answer would be "yes, but the original looked better to me personally".

Answer (score 2):

A is fine.  But B would not be likely in contemporary AmE (I can't speak for BrE). It seems quaint, outdated.

Once the reader gets past that, I suppose A and B mean the same—provided that the reader catches that you are using "so" to mean "to such a degree" rather than just "in such a manner". The first example, A,  leaves no such ambiguity;  "so much" is clearly a matter of degree.

Answer (score 0):

"a." is idiomatic AmE.

"b." might appear in a written text, but *today* one is not likely to hear it spoken in AmE. Present-day AmE speakers tend to avoid placing "so" in front of the PP of the verb in that way, although [100 years ago](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(had%20so%20changed)%2C(had%20changed%20so%20much)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28had%20so%20changed%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28had%20changed%20so%20much%29%3B%2Cc0), things were different.